# C++ - Initialize 2 copies of object owned by different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

Suppose I have thread A and thread B. Each thread owns a copy of the same object (let's call it "Foo" for simplicity). Certain pieces of data in Foo are initialized from a file on startup. So that means that on startup, I have to set the data read from the file in both copies of Foo. If no data is read from the file, then I still want to set the same data instance in both copies of Foo and not have each thread initialize the data separately.

Due to the architecture of the software I am working on, I am unable to perform this work on construction of either copy of Foo. So I am forced to do some type of Initialize() or similar method that is called after construction of the object. Since this all happens during the initialization phase of the application, I do not need to be concerned about thread-safety, but I am still concerned about the cleanliness of this solution. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
ThreadA::Start()
{
    ...

    // Initialize() will read the data from the file if it exists. Otherwise, it will set default values.
    m_Foo.Initialize();

    // Now call Initialize() for thread B's copy of Foo while running in thread A but before thread B is even started. Pass in thread A's copy of Foo to set the values with. This should be safe to do since thread B has not even started yet.
    m_ThreadB.GetFoo().Initialize(m_Foo);

    ...
}
```

Is this the cleanest way to initialize the data in both copies of Foo? Thanks!

Comment: If `m_Foo` is indeed the same instance between both threads, wouldn't its `Initialize` need to be synchronized?

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify there. m_Foo is the thread A copy of the Foo class. The Foo object returned by m_ThreadB.GetFoo() is thread B's copy of the Foo class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over thinking it because there are threads.  If no threads are running, then you can use any method you wish to initialize them because there are no race cases.  Don't even think about the threads.  For the rest of this, I will call ThreadA and threadB BugbearA and BugbearB instead.

If you only have two Bugbears, and BugbearA always starts before BugbearB, then your solution is the best one can ever come up with.

If the situation is actually more complicated than you let on, I would recommend refactoring the data to have a shared object containing the data that may be initialized from a file, and an unshared object For each Bugbear.  The first Bugbear to Start() initializes the shared object.  All threads copy that data into their own Foo and start.

This refactor will also set you up for multithreading, if you need it later.  All you have to do is provide proper synchronization for the shared object.